# Quiero hacer un input para buscar sin importar si se utiliza mayuscula o minusculas

Tags: javascript, html, regex, input

Estoy haciendo un buscador mediante un input el cual me gustaria que sin importar como escribas el producto (Con Mayusculas o Minisculas) sea tomado de igual manera. (Que sea caseInsensitive).

```
let buscador = document.getElementById("producto");
    buscador.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    if (e.target.value == "huawei") {
        myFunction();
    } else if (e.target.value == "samsung") {
        myFunction1();
    } else if (e.target.value == "iphone") {
        myFunction2();
    } else {
        cel1.style.display = "block";
        cel2.style.display = "block";
        cel3.style.display = "block";
        Swal.fire(
            'ERROR',
            'No se encontro tu producto',
            'error'
          )
    }
})
```

Comment: podes guardar el value provisionalmente en una variable y usar el metodo de strings toLowerCase() para que convierta todo a minusculas y recien ahi hacer los ifs

Comment: Pasa el valor que vas a comparar a minúsculas con `toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar algo como esto:

```js
function search(){
  let buscador = document.getElementById("product");
  var text = buscador.value;
  var rs = text.toLowerCase().includes('samsung'.toLowerCase());
  var rs2 = text.toLowerCase().includes('iphone'.toLowerCase());
  console.log(rs);
  console.log(rs2);
}
```

```html
<input id="product" value="" />

<button onclick="search()">Buscar</button>
```

Servirá perfectamente para buscar si tiene la palabra, si la tiene devolverá un **TRUE** y con ello podrás hacer validaciones.

Espero haberte ayudado.